# Can I import the friend's Email Address or Phone Number from Facebook through javascript api?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-java-api

Is it require any permission except allow to my app. My code is as follows..

FB.api({ method: 'fql.query',

query: 'SELECT name,pic_square,birthday,sex,profile_url,website,email,email_hashes FROM user

WHERE uid='+friend.id },

```
     function(response) {

     alert("friends website:: "+response[0].website);

     alert("friends email :: "+response[0].email); 

     alert("friends email_hashes:: "+response[0].email_hashes[0]); 

     } } );
```

First alert is returning proper website information, but the second and third alert is

giving null and undefined/null( Except email everything is coming proper, but not email

address).

Answer (score 0):

No, you **do not** get access to friend’s email addresses – you can only get the email address for the current app user, with the `email` permission. There is no such thing as a `friends_email` permission.

And user phone numbers are not accessible via the API any more **at all**, not even for your current user. If you require that info, you have to have the user give it to you themselves via a form or something.